# Express $1$ Quad/yr in units of kW*hr/day/person

Tags: unit-of-measure

For calculating the -per person- part, we are going to be using the population of the USA, i.e, $3\times10^8$.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @an4s 1 quad = 2.9329 x 10^11 kW*hr... then I divided both sides by 365 days to get to -> 8.0353 x 10^8 kW*hr / day.... then I divide it by the number of people. I don't know though if what I did was right?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all we know that:

$$x\space\space\text{quad}=1055055852620000000\cdot x\space\space\text{joule}=\frac{2637639631550\cdot x}{9}\space\space\text{kWh}\tag1$$

So, when we have $x$ quad per year we know that one year has the following number of days:

$$\eta\approx365.242199\tag2$$

And the number of people in a country is:

$$\mathcal{P}\tag3$$

So, when we want to find kWh/day/person we need to find:

$$\text{E}\approx\frac{\left(\frac{\frac{2637639631550\cdot x}{9}}{365.242199}\right)}{\mathcal{P}}=\frac{376805661650000000}{469597113}\cdot\frac{x}{\mathcal{P}}\approx8.02402\cdot10^8\cdot\frac{x}{\mathcal{P}}\tag4$$